# putting variables into vectors to be used in subsequent function (R)

Tags: r

i have a question regarding my second function which is not producing what i wanted to

```
#example for mt-cars
selected_cyl_6 <- subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==6)
selected_cyl_4 <- subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==4)

count <- function(variable,group) {
  sum(group[[deparse(substitute(variable))]]== 4)
}
#now i would like to create a matrix with the results like here below:
#example
u<-count(gear,selected_cyl_6)
v<-count(carb,selected_cyl_6)
w<-count(gear,selected_cyl_4)
x<-count(carb,selected_cyl_4)

matrix(c(u,v,w,x), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2, nrow=2)
```

this is a feasible option, however i would love to convert the lines above into a function because in my dataset there are a lot more variables and i would save a lot of time and code length. i tried it with the following code:

```
variables_of_interest <- c("gear","carb")
groups_of_interest <- c("selected_cyl_6","selected_cyl_4")


alteration_multiple <- function(variable_vector, group_vector){
  m.results <- matrix(0, nrow = length(variable_vector), ncol = length(group_vector))
  rownames(m.results) <- variable_vector
  colnames(m.results) <- group_vector
  for (t in 1:length(group_vector)) {
    for (i in 1:length(variable_vector)) {
      m.results[i,t] <- count(group_vector[t],variable_vector[i])
    }
    print(m.results)
  }
}
alteration_multiple(variable_vector=variables_of_interest, group_vector=groups_of_interest)
```

any suggestions? thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we redefine the inputs and `count` it can be considerably simplified and shortened.  (`selected_cyl_4` and `selected_cyl_6` are as in the question.)

```
groups <- list(cyl_6 = selected_cyl_6, cyl_4 = selected_cyl_4) ##
variables <- c(gear = "gear", carb = "carb") ##
count <- function(v, g) sum(g[[v]] == 4)

outer(variables, groups, Vectorize(count))
```

giving:

```
     cyl_6 cyl_4
gear     4     8
carb     4     0
```

**Note:** If we did want to start with precisely the inputs defined in the question (`variables_of_interest`, `groups_of_interest`) then use these two lines in place of the lines marked ## above.

```
groups <- mget(groups_of_interest)
variables <- setNames(nm = variables_of_interest)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use quoted strings to refer to data and variables, we need to modify your two functions.

The main task is to redefine the `count` function so that it can handle your proposed inputs. We can use `eval` and `as.name` to do this.

#### new count function

```
count2 <- function(variable,group) {
    sum(eval(as.name(group))[[variable]]== 4)
}
```

#### new alteration function

```
alteration_multiple2 <- function(variable_vector, group_vector){
    m.results <- matrix(0, nrow = length(variable_vector), ncol = length(group_vector))
    rownames(m.results) <- variable_vector
    colnames(m.results) <- group_vector
    for (t in 1:length(group_vector)) {
        for (i in 1:length(variable_vector)) {
            m.results[i,t] <- count2(variable_vector[i], group_vector[t])
        }
    }
    return(m.results)
}
```

#### result

```
variables_of_interest <- c("gear","carb")
groups_of_interest <- c("selected_cyl_6","selected_cyl_4")
alteration_multiple2(variable_vector=variables_of_interest, group_vector=groups_of_interest)

     selected_cyl_6 selected_cyl_4
gear              4              8
carb              4              0
```

#### Another way to define our alteration function

We can avoid a `for` loop and execute our function using `matrix`, `apply`, and `expand.grid`.

```
alteration_multiple3 <- function(variables, groups){ 
    matrix(
        apply(
        expand.grid(variables, groups), 1,
          function(x) count2(x[1],x[2])),
    nrow = length(variables),
    ncol = length(groups),
    dimnames = list(variables, groups))
    }
```

Comment: this is great. thanks! the key was to use eval(as.name()) for subsetted data. however I am not sure what is the difference between the group and the variable vector and why it is used different in the count2 function?